# Как вывести цену на график?

Tags: python, plotly

Получить данные с CSV файла получилось так же получилось сделать график и сохранить его в картинку. Вопрос такой, как на графике вывести текущею цену?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=df['Date'] , y=df['AAPL'])])
fig.write_image("finance.jpeg")
```

Результат
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы выражаетесь точно, то "вывести **текущею** цену" это значит вывести цену "на сегодня". Значит на графике надо нарисовать (дорисовать) отдельно точку, используя  тот-же scatter-plot, но другой цвет и больший размер маркера и в качестве Х указать сегодняшнюю дату, а в качестве Y -  сегодняшнюю цену. В случае желания - значение "текущей цены" можно добавить в виде дополнительной надписи на графике.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но не могли бы вы привести код?

Comment: Какой функцией рисовать - вы знаете, параметр - marker, ну например так:marker=dict(color='LightSkyBlue', size=20). "Сегодняшние" данные надеюсь сможете подставить самостоятельно.